# Identify the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Consider the quotient ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$. Could somebody help me to identify $R$ with some well-known ring?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the two natural ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{F}_2[x] \to \mathbb{F}_2$, $x \mapsto 0$ and $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}_2$ and let $P = \mathbb{F}_2[x] \times_{\mathbb{F}_2} \mathbb{Z}$ be their [fiber product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29#Commutative_Rings). The element $(x,0)$ satisfies $2(x,0)=0$. It generates $P$: If $(f,z) \in P$, i.e. $f \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(0) = z \bmod 2$, then one checks $(f,z)=g((x,0))$ for any lift $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of $f$.  It follows that there is a surjective homomorphism of rings $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x) \to P$ which maps $[f]$ to $(x,1)$. It is not hard to show that it is also injective, and therefore an isomorphism.

Geometrically, $\mathrm{Spec}(R)\cong \mathrm{Spec}(P)$ is the gluing of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_2[x])$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ along the closed points $(x) \sim (2)$. You get a more classical example by replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{F}_2[y]$ and the point $(2)$ by $(y)$, because then we glue two affine lines over $\mathbb{F}_2$ along their origins, which results in the union of the two coordinate axes, which has the coordinate ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(xy)$.  See Karl Schwede's paper [Gluing schemes and a scheme without closed points](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/schwede03.pdf) for more about these gluings.

Comment: Righto. My first thought was to liken OP’s ring to the affine ring of the union of the two axes in $2$-space.

Comment: Sorry for asking in a question made long time ago, it is a fantastic answer. I think you wanted to say the map $[x]\mapsto (x,0)$ instead of "$[f]$ to $(x,1)$?" And for a general polynomial $f$ the map would be $[f]\mapsto ([f]_2, f(0))$?

Comment: Yes -  probably.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$ has as its additive group $\mathbb{Z}\oplus x\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ so every element is an integer $a$ plus a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with zero constant term. $$(a+p(x))(b+q(x))=ab+[b]_2p(x)+[a]_2q(x)+p(x)q(x)$$

Comment: This describes the ring, but it does not associate it with some other well-known ring - this was the question.

Comment: This ring is the result of adjoining unity to $x\Bbb Z_2[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a basic comment that might help some people to understand what is the structure of the elements of these rings without going into advanced mathematics:

Let $\sum a_i X^i \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ then divide coefficients $a_i$ with $i \ge 1$ by 2 to obtain:

$a_i = (2q_i+r_i) = 2q_i+r_i$

$a_iX^i = (2q_i+r_i)X^i = 2q_iX^i+r_iX^i$

Then you can write the original polynomial as:

$(a_0 + \sum r_i X^i) + (\sum 2q_iX^i)$ where $r_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2, q_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

In the quotient, the right part disappears since it is contained in the ideal $\langle 2X \rangle$ and therefore you obtain:

$a_0 + \sum r_i X^i$ with $r_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2, q_i \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This answer is no different of that by Matt Samuel...

Comment: @JoseBrox for me the phrase $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$ has as its additive group $\mathbb{Z}\oplus x\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ without further explanation is difficult to grasp. However, i understand that there are other people who won't need this further explanation.

Comment: I was trying to grasp why $$ \mathbb Z [x]/(2x)\cong \mathbb Z \oplus  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z   \oplus  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \oplus \dots$$
This "comment" helped me somewhat to see why.