# $R/(ab)\cong R/(a)\oplus R/(b)$, for $a$ and $b$ non-associate irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $a,b$ be non-associate irreducible elements in UFD $R$. Then 
>    $$R/(ab)\cong R/(a)\oplus R/(b)$$

What is the isomorphism function I have to define?

Does $f(r+(ab))=(r+(a),r+(b))$ works here? If yes, how to show it is surjective?

I also need to understand something, Why do we need UFD?

Comment: Are you sure about the statement?

Comment: Pairwise nonassociate tho.  OP's statement is definitely true in a PID.

Comment: The statement was question in my friend exam. 

@TedShifrin $a,b$ cannot be equals since $a,b$ are non-associate , ( the definition I have for associate $a|b$ and $b|a$,or $(a)=(b)$. ) .

Comment: @D_S,Does that mean the statement is wrong in UFD?

Comment: I don't expect it to be true in a UFD, I'm currently trying to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Try $a=2$, $b=4$ or $a=4$, $b=6$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: then $b$ isn't irreducible. :)

Comment: @AlexW: I guess I have failed reading. I withdraw.

Comment: @D_S: maybe $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $a = X, b = 2$? According to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020656/identify-the-ring-mathbbzx-2x/1020664, $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X)$ is isomorphic to the fiber product $\mathbb{Z} \times_{\mathbb{F}_{2}} \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$, so unless $\mathbb{Z} \times_{\mathbb{F}_{2}} \mathbb{F}_{2}[X] \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$, perhaps this is a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this true is without requiring that $R$ be a PID. Consider the example $R = \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $a = 2, b = X$. Then the statement would imply $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2X) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$. The latter ring has four idempotent elements, namely $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$ and $(0, 0)$. The former ring, however, has only trivial idempotents by degree arguments (the square of any nonconstant polynomial with an odd leading coefficient also has an odd leading coefficient of higher degree).

Comment: What is the wrong in @Tsemo Aristide proof? I couldn't find it

Comment: @Leonardo: D_S spotted it early - $a$ and $b$ need not generate the unit ideal. In the example above, for instance, $\langle 2, X \rangle$ is not the unit ideal - the quotient $R/\langle 2, X \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: I see where I made a mistake to show they are comaximal .. Thanks dude

Comment: @Leonardo: glad I could help! :)

Comment: Excellent answer.  I think I have come up with another example, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @D_S: Thank you! I wouldn't have posted without your comments above. I'm trying to read yours, but I might be a bit too slow for it at the moment... :) It seems to have a much nicer geometric interpretation than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[X,Y], a = X -1, b = X +1$.  Then $$R/(ab) = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2-1)$$ I am pretty sure this is not isomorphic to $R/(a) \times R/(b) \cong \mathbb{C}[X] \times \mathbb{C}[Y] \cong \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(XY)$.

If they were isomorphic, then their prime ideal structures would have to be the same.

Let  $A  = \mathbb{C}[X]/(XY)$, $B = \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2-1)$.  These rings are both one dimensional and Noetherian.  Every Noetherian ring has only finitely many minimal prime ideals.

The minimal prime ideals of $A$ are $\mathfrak q_1 = (X)/(XY)$ and $\mathfrak q_2 = (Y)/(XY)$.  The minimal prime ideals of $B$ are $\mathfrak p_1 = (X+1)/(X^2-1)$ and $\mathfrak p_2 = (X-1)/(X^2-1)$.

For the ring $B$, every maximal ideal is of the form $(X-z_1,Y-z_2)/(X^2-1)$, where $z_1 = \pm 1$ and $z_2$ is any complex number.  Then every maximal ideal of $B$ contains exactly *one* of the minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak p_1, \mathfrak p_2$.

On the other hand, $(X,Y)/(XY)$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ which contains both minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak q_1, \mathfrak q_2$.

Comment: I was thinking about algebraic varieties when constructing this example: I wanted one example where the irreducible components were disjoint, and one where they were not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proof for a PID

Let $f:R\rightarrow R/a\oplus R/b$ defined by $f(x)= [x]_a\oplus [x]_b$,
$f(ab)=0$, so $f$ induces $g:R/ab\rightarrow R/a\oplus R/b$, $a,b$ are not associated implies that the ideal generated by $a,b$ is $R$ $1=ua+vb$,  so $[ua]_b=1$ and $[vb]_a=1$ this implies that for $x,y\in R$ $g(yua+xvb)=[yua+xvb]_a+[yua+xvb]_b=[xvb]_a\oplus [yua]_b=[x]_a+[y]_b$ so $g$ is surjective.

$g(x)=0$ implies that $[x]_a=0, [x]_b=0$, $a,b$ divides $x$ hence $ab$ divides $x$ since $R$ is a UFD.

Comment: Why are $(a), (b)$ comaximal?  This would be true in a PID, not necessarily a UFD.

Comment: Property 2 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#

Comment: I don't see how $a, b$ having a unit GCD implies that they generate comaximal ideals.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why  $1=ua+vb$ ? if $d|a$ and $d|b$, then $b=kd$, and $a=dt$. So , $ka=(dk)t=bt$. which means $a,b$ are associate . Contradiction. Is this right ??

Comment: I edit my comment? can anyone check it please